# Error : connot find name 'ContactField' in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I have to save the contact using Ionic2 but when I run the app using cmd I'm getting an error. I have installed `cordova-plugin-contacts`

Here is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Contacts} from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/contact/user-add/user-add.html',
})
export class UserAddPage {
  name:any;
  number:any
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  addcontact(){
    var contact=Contacts.create();
    contact.displayName=this.name;
    contact.nickname=this.name;

    var contactfield=new ContactField();
    contactfield.type="mobile";
    contactfield.value=this.number;
    contactfield.pref=true;

    var numbersection=[];
    numbersection.push(contactfield);
    contact.phoneNumbers=numbersection;

    contact.save().then((data)=>{
      console.log('saved',data);
    },(error)=>{
      console.log('error',error);
    })
  }
}
```

After that I'm getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import it like this:

```
import { Contact, ContactField } from 'ionic-native';
```